# Need to know which plant/tree is that?

Tags: identification, trees

I just moved to this house and have this plant. In winter, all the leaves were fallen off and last month, all the new leaves and flower blossomed up.. There is no fruit on it right now and it's around 10 feet tall.

If anybody knows, please let me know which plant is that.
[image][image]

Comment: Seeing the flowers would have helped, what colour were they? Shape? How many petals? Were they scented?

Answer (score 4):

It seems a *Prunus armenica* (Apricot). Prunus (mainly the cherry trees) have the typical points on the stalk of leaves. The redish of the stalk, the form and colour of the leaves tell me an Apricot.  But I'm not so used on ornamental cultivars.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be apricot. I have both cherry and apricot in the yard and your pictures resemble the apricot.